# Are the straps in my patio chairs supposed to be loose?

Tags: furniture, patio

I bought a patio set and underneath the cushions are straps but they all look loose, are they supposed to be like that?

[image]

Comment: If all the seats are like that, then odds are really good that's how the manufacturer designed it. If just one is like that, then odds are good it's a defect.

Answer (score 6):

If the cushions are really thick - 4"+... then loose webbing makes sense.   If the cushions are thinner then the webbing will eventually break.    It really depends on the cushion that is going on it.

Reasoning... Thick cushion that is sturdy that goes all the way to the edge of the chair will have little give.   The loose strapping allows the cushion to adjust when you sit in it.

Answer (score 5):

Chairs without cushions will have the webbing pulled tight so you don't sink into the chair making it difficult to get out of. Chairs with cushions will have loose webbing to allow the cushion to sink into the chair for stability.

Answer (score 3):

Look into suspension bridge theory a bit and you'll find that as the sag of a span approaches zero the tension in the span approaches infinity. There *must* be some sag, for both structural reasons and derriere comfort.

Also, few materials have zero stretch. Even if the straps were snug initially, they're not going to stay that way.